# Python: best way to use ExitStack to avoid multiple with statement

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

I have following code to where I use ExitStack instead of with statement.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from contextlib import ExitStack
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


@contextmanager
def myfile():
    temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt')
    temp_file.seek(0)
    yield temp_file
    os.unlink(temp_file.name)


with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = []
    for idx in range(5):
        files.append(stack.enter_context(myfile()))
    # do something with the files
```

Above code gives 5 error messages like below

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpbupwinzt.txt'
```

Am I using ExitStack in a wrong way. What would be the correct way to do above thing.

**Note**: I can not change `myfile()` function but I can change rest of the code.

Comment: Does it work if you use multiple `with` statements?

Comment: `with myfile() as f1:
    with myfile() as f2:
        # do something here`
I get same error with multiple with statement as well.

Comment: Well then I don't think the error is in the ExitStack, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an explanation. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile):

> [A TemporaryFile] will be destroyed as soon as it is closed (including an implicit
> close when the object is garbage collected).

However, you are unlinking the file in the progam (last line of `myfile`). When the test program ends, the garbage collection fails to close and unlink the file and prints an error. In other words, the error is not occurring in the `with` statement.

A simple solution is to disable the automatic removal:

```
NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt', delete=False)
```

However I think the `seek(0)` on a new file is unnecessary and the whole `myfile` does nothing the `NamedTemporaryFile` is not already doing, so you could use it directly:

```
with ExitStack() as stack:
    files = []
    for idx in range(5):
        files.append(stack.enter_context(NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.txt')))
```